# Starting multiple Services with the same Intent but different requestCode uses same Object

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have an object that schedules a service through the AlarmManager like this:

```
public void schedule(MyEnum enum) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    intent.setAction(enum.name());

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable("MyEnum", content);
    intent.putExtra("Bundle", args);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, enum.ordinal(),
        intent, 0);  
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
}
```

The service:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("this: " + this);
    }
}
```

The way I start the scheduler:

```
scheduler.schedule(MyEnum.ONE);
scheduler.schedule(MyEnum.TWO);
```

And What I see in the logs:

```
MyService@41ea7858
MyService@41ea7858
```

I tried using a BroadcastReceiver, I also played with the flags, but same result.
Then I tried something like that:

```
button1.setOnClickListener() { scheduler.scheduler(MyEnum.ONE); }
button2.setOnClickListener() { scheduler.scheduler(MyEnum.TWO); }
```

And if I click on button1 then button2 right away, I see the same Id in the logs. But if I leave a bit more time between the clicks, I get two different Ids...

Any idea what's going on and how to avoid that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can not.**

Services and BroadcastReceivers are different from Activities in such a way, that there can only be one instance at the same time.
Only when the first instance is destroyed, a new is created. That's what you experience with your second experiment.

Comment: I see... My original goal was to download data in the background at specific intervals. And each download is independent. Like: download data1 every 5h, download data2 every 6h etc. I've read that the best way to schedule repetitive tasks is by using the AlarmManager (rather than a Service), such that the tasks can be executed while the device is asleep.
One way to solve my problem would be to have different IntentSerivce (one for each data I guess). But how about kicking off an AsyncTask in onHandleIntent? Does it make sense? What would be a better approach? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need different services. Just pass your data to a single IntentService, it will handle all request sequentially on it's own.

Comment: Your answer is correct.
Regarding the other part of my problem, I solved it by using an Provider to inject an object that will download the different files (based on the data passed to the Intent).